# accessing a web application from SoapUI using Groovy script

Tags: rest, groovy, soapui

I am new to groovy. Is it possible to access a web application from SoapUI using a Groovy script step?

Comment: Are you talking about SOAP the protocol: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP or SoapUI the test tool: https://www.soapui.org/ ? Please clarify your question. Also show us what you have already tried.

Comment: I am using SOAP UI tool for testing  some REST services  .   The problem is that - After getting the response of first service (POST)  I need to manually  update some content on the Application  before running the second REST service (PUT), if not updated there will be error in Response , I want to automate  this mid manual process of updating content in application . Can it be possible through Groovy coding. I am sorry  am not from coding background but started leaning  groovy these days  so   was  just searching any groovy  code related to it  but couldn't find any :((

Comment: Will Appreciate if anyone could provide me any example related to it

Comment: I modified your question, and the tags, to be less ambiguous. However, from the information you provided, then only answer that anyone can possibly give you is "Yes." If you need anymore than that, you will have to give us much more information. The specific information that we need is described in article [ask], and more details are in article [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Groovy can make HTTP requests (SOAP is fine) that could be used to interact with a web page, if it were designed to handle that.  Most web pages are interactive via javascript and HTML fields though, which doesn't really line up with what you're describing here.

So: yes, if the target handles it. It's better to use a well-designed API for interaction though.

Comment: I am using SOAP UI tool for testing some REST services . The problem is that - After getting the response of first service (POST) I need to manually update some content on the Application before running the second REST service (PUT), if not updated there will be error in Response , I want to automate this mid manual process of updating content in application . Can it be possible through Groovy coding. I am sorry am not from coding background but started leaning groovy these days so was just searching any groovy code related to it but couldn't find any :((

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing here is property transfer and SoapUi handles it well.

You can use Groovy to write the value returned from the Post request into a variable that all steps can see.  E.g. test property.  You can then pull this into your request for the Put operation at test run time.

You can use Property Transfer.

My preferred method would be a third option where you can get the value from a previous step in the Put step.

The Smartbear site has lots of really good tutorials that describe each of the above in very good detail.